# Are these two code snippets using IQueryable and .AsParallel equivalent?

Tags: c#, entity-framework, parallel-processing, task-parallel-library

I am working on some pretty basic TPL code, and I ran across a situation where I was curious if the following two snippets are equivalent:

```
myEnumerable.AsParallel().Select(e =>
{
    //do some work that takes awhile
    return new Thing(e);
}

myEnumerable.Select(e =>
{
    //do some work that takes awhile
    return new Thing(e);
}.AsParallel()
```

Also - if they are, in fact, equivalent, is their equivalency something that can change as defined by the TPL interface with IEnumerable extension methods?  Or am I just setting myself up to break my code when I update to .NET V{Whatever}?

For background, `myEnumerable` is an EF table (entity) that I have not yet enumerated (made the DB round trip) on.

My desired behavior is for the DB call to be made synchronously, get a List back, and operate upon the list in parallel (make a bunch of web service calls on the List in parallel)

Comment: Care to explain the downvote so I can improve the question?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

> I was curious if the following two snippets are equivalent

No, they aren't. Your former code will *attempt* to partition the `IEnumerable` in order to execute it in parallel. You latter code will project elements to your `Select` sequentially, and receive the filtered `IEnumerable`. Only what comes after the `AsParallel` will run in parallel.

Note that LINQ-To-Entities doesn't really work with `AsParallel`. Usually, it will cause your code to run slower then it will sequentially. Also, `DbContext` is not thread-safe. That code will potentially cause more harm then good.

What you can do is first query the database, and once the data is in-memory, use `AsParallel`.

> My desired behavior is for the DB call to be made synchronously, get a
>   List back, and operate upon the list in parallel (make a bunch of web
>   service calls on the List in parallel)

If you want to make multiple web service calls via the returned data, you can take advantage of the natural async API that exists for making such requests. For example, if you're querying an HTTP endpoint, you can exploit `HttpClient` and use it in combination with `async-await`, and execute queries concurrently, without needing any extra threads.

Comment: Unfortunately I don't have async-await available (hooray legacy systems and archaic coding standards), but I might be able to cobble something together that will work like that.  I'll give it a shot and update in a few minutes, thanks!

Comment: Which version of the .NET framework are you working on?

Comment: 4.0, but I'm not allowed to use async/await because the manager is worried future engineers won't understand how it works.

Comment: One thing - can you please add the "Only what comes after AsParallel is parallel." chunk that @usr included below?  That helped me understand what was going on a bit better.

Comment: @Pheonixblade9 Tell that manager he has nothing to worry about :X. Just to make sure, you are familiar with the [`async-await` support for .NET 4.0](https://www.nuget.org/packages/Microsoft.Bcl.Async), right?

Comment: yep, it's something I use all the time.  Unfortunately, consulting enforces a very interesting set of rules on you, sometimes ;)

Answer (score 2):

Only what comes after `AsParallel` is parallel. Everything before it is simply the sequential input stream to the parallel query (exception: if the input is already a parallel query it will be treated as such).

PLINQ cannot parallelize an existing query because it has no way of dissecting it. The input is an opaque `IEnumerable`.

> My desired behavior is for the DB call to be made synchronously, get a List back, and operate upon the list in parallel

Use the first code snippet.

> make a bunch of web service calls on the List in parallel

The TPL is terrible at choosing the optimal degree of parallelism for IO-bound tasks. Use `WithDegreeOfParallelism` to pick an appropriate DOP for your particular IO load.

Comment: I don't believe I'm using PLINQ - just LINQ-Entities.  Unless PLINQ comes for free when using the TPL?

Comment: @Pheonixblade9 PLINQ stands for "Parallel LINQ", which is implemented using the TPL (Task Parallel Library). When you use `AsParallel`. You're using PLINQ.

Comment: I know what PLINQ is :)  I just didn't know if it came automatically when using the TPL.  Thanks!

Answer (score 2):

No, they are not equivalent.

The first expression will run the work in the `Select` in parallel when consumed.

The second expression will run the work in the `Select` in one thread, to produce items for the parallel execution. What you do to consume the second expression will run in parallel, but that is likely to be something trivial that doesn't benefit from being parallelised.